# handlebars access global variable: if statement

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I've got a hbs template where I've got an array of objects and a boolean toggle variable (toggles the template behavior), let's say:

```
{
  objs: list,
  mode: true
}
```

I'm not able to access the `mode` variable when inside the loop over `objs` (the context is changed). What I want is to make an if-statement using the upper variable. I found that I can write a custom helper. But is there no other way to access the variable? I also found out, that inside the loop the variable is accessible via `{{../mode}}` - but still, don't know how to access that.

Comment: maybe its worth mentioning, I was looking for reference to global variable inside an each loop. this was actually what i was looking for thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally, I've found a solution:

```
{{#if ../mode}}xyz{{/if}}
```